# the .catch is not activated when an error occurs in the web request

Tags: angular

I am trying to consume the web service from this url:

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post
```

I created a provider to consume a web service in a file called `provider`. and in `app/app.component.ts` I call this provider to pass a url and make the web request

```
export class AppComponent  {
name = 'Angular';
constructor(public serviceProvider: ServiceProvider) {

setTimeout(()=>{
  let oSendData = {
    title: 'foo',
    body: 'bar',
    userId: 1,
  };
  this.serviceProvider
    .post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post5', oSendData)
    .then((data) => {
      alert("success");
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      alert("problem service");

    })
    .finally(() => {
    });
  },3000)
 }
}

@Injectable()
export class ServiceProvider {
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,

  ) {}

public post(url, params?: object) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({}),
    };

  
    return this.http
      .post(url, params, httpOptions)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
      .toPromise();
  }

public handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(this, error.status);
    //this.showAlert(); // i am getting error
    return [];
  }

  showAlert(){
    alert("show alert")
  }

}
```

but I want to validate that when I get an error from this request, the `.catch` is activated `(in app.component.ts)` , in this case I added a `5` so that a 404 error occurs (`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post5`) , but the `.catch` is never fired.

what am I doing wrong? or how can I get the `.catch` to fire in case an error occurs while consuming the web service?

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ra5sja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.catch never fires because you have handled about it on `pipe` on service function on this part.

```
.pipe(catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)))
```

And on handleError function, you have handled the error and have returned `[]` value.

Therefore, that `Promise` will return the value always and will never throw error.
If you want to make `.catch` work, it will be needed to throw the exception on `handleError` function like

```
public handleError(error) {
   ...
   throw "Unable to handle";
}
```

Comment: thanks!! I learned something new today, thank you very much! Friend one last question, do you know why I can't call the `showAlert()` function when `handleError` is triggered? I am getting error ..

Comment: Can you try `window.alert("Show Error");`?

Comment: with your code the alert is triggered. In my case I want to call the function `showAlert()` but inside  of `handleError` the `this` does not contain `showAlert()` there is my live code

Comment: You are not able to call `this.showAlert` because you lost `this` so it is needed to bind `this`. There are two ways. One is to use arrow function on `catchError` like `catchError((error) => { this.handleError(error); });` and the other way is to use `bind` function like `catchError(this.handleError.bind(this));`.

Comment: thanks genius!!  with this sintaxis `this.http.get(this.sUrl + inUrl, httpOptions).pipe( catchError((error) => { this.handleError(error); })).toPromise();`   I am getting this error https://i.imgur.com/4lzAAEn.jpg

Comment: missing return there.

Comment: check my answer. you can use showAlert function. the important problem is, `this` does not point out ServiceProvider, so you should bind `this`.

Comment: So `.pipe(catchError((error) => { return this.handleError(error); });` will work. Or `catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))`.

Comment: I put the return and I get the same error. I was able to solve the error with the other path you indicated, but out of curiosity I want to know how to fix it this way.

Comment: on `handleError` function, you have returned value of `[]` or have thrown something? You should return sth on `handleError` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
.pipe(catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)))
```

You should let `handleError` function know what `this` constructor points out.

Comment: @yavg This one is a simple fix, no?